# How do I link from one Stack Overflow question to others?

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

What is the correct way to link from one Stack Overflow question to another one? For example, if I want to reference another question or answer from my question, how would I do that?
Should I just create a static link or is there some way that creates something which is a little more dynamic and understood by Stack Overflow as an internal link? I did not find the answer in the formatting full reference.

[example static link: stackoverflows-related-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393505/stackoverflows-related-questions)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just create a static link, they don't change (but the question can be moved for some reason)

Comment: And even with a static link, SO could at some point in the future provide any kind of "dynamic" behaviour just by knowing what an SO question link looks like.

Comment: This sounds fine to me but I want to leave this open a little longer to see if anyone else says anything

Comment: I would like some more detail.  On the right hand side of stack pages there are "linked questions".  How do those get there?  Where does one create this link, in a comment / question / answer / elsewhere?  Thanks!

Comment: What about Links to Questions that have their title changed?

Answer (score 12):

Since November 2010, raw links from the same site are automatically converted into clickable links with the title that is current when saving the post.

So,

> See http​://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483 for details.

shows as:

See [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483) for details.

Comment: how about links to other stackexchange sites, i.e. a link on stackoverflow.com to another question on e.g. superuser.com?

Comment: this method does not work in comment. for me at least

Answer (score 4):

Pretty old question but in case someone is looking, but for a few years now, each question and answer has a tiny *share* link just on the left below it, which when you click on, gives you a link that you can put on any other site.