# Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, stack-exchange

It often happens that people will refer to other questions by simply pasting the full link to this question, especially on Meta.

Would it be a good idea to detect such links, and replace them directly by a formatted link on their current title?

Example:

```
 You can try formatting at this
 question:
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox
```

Would be automatically changed in:

> You can try formatting at this
>   question: [Stack Exchange
>   Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox)

It would make links given by new users (unaware of the full syntax) more elegant, and it would also be faster when more regular (and lazy) users want to point to another question without making the usual "see it [at this other place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox)"

---

**Edit:** Note that this behaviour is implemented already for the "possible duplicate" auto comments, so the question here is not about "how to do this technically".

Comment: Would be problematic for questions like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45046/ unless we included some manner of truncation (and then, how would we decide how long it should be?)

Comment: Question titles change, would you want them to be updated or not? would you like the "closed" of a closed question to be included or not?

Comment: @Downvoter - it's only an help on the moment the message is posted, so only with the current title. No need to update it further. About the closed, not sure, it doesn't bring a lot of information at this point, only noise, probably.

Comment: @ccornet - the new limit of 150 chars makes it already more "presentable". Either way, most of time the copied link contains already a long part of the title. So not much difference in this case.

Comment: @Gnoupi I never caught the update on the title character limits. Thanks!

Comment: Adding a bounty. Please please implement this. It is so annoying to have to copy over the question title and link it

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/advanced-syntax-ideas/1019#1019

Comment: Adding another bounty. This is **SOOOO annoying** and doesn't deserve the status-completed tag yet

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox

Comment: I created a feature request to implement this functionality in comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments

Comment: The request is not fully completed, it is still not completed for comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For intra-site links (like, SO -> SO) this is now supported.

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox
```

becomes*

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox)

Like with [tag rewrites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482) this is done on post submission <s>and is not currently reflected in the editor preview</s>. It will always insert the current title into the post, at post creation time. However, should the title subsequently change it will not be updated unless the post is edited.

<sub>*Note that although the **old** title of the question is in the link, the new one is inserted.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Is this triggered on edit?   Will it be rolled out to the stack exchange sites?

Comment: @Alex - it is triggered on edit, and will be available on all of the SE sites within the hour.

Comment: Would you consider adding this for [inter-SE links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59569/146482) too?

Comment: @Kevin: Could you add this to comments? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox

Comment: @Arjan - it will always insert the current title into the post, at post creation time.  However, should the title subsequently change it will not be updated unless the post is edited.

Comment: I guess it's by design that the Markdown `<bare url>` syntax gets one the title too? (If not: currently the `<..>` syntax also is replaced by the title.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to always work though. Are there some special rules? And it definitely doesn't work in comments.

Comment: Sometimes it works too well: sometimes even links in code blocks are changed, and also links that are explicitly linked manually to avoid replacement (like in revision 1 and 2 [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/74274/revisions)).

Comment: Now that this post is on MSE but the link still refers to MSO, editing this very post seems to break the auto-linking, while a bare URL on MSO [pointing to](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/251360/1) MSE [works just fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hLvYY.png): maybe auto-linking on MSE should also support links to other metas? And curious, @Kevin: the revision history of this very post [currently shows the bare link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lbjUJ.png). Does that imply that the HTML is rendered on the fly for the revision history?

Comment: Ah, it seems that redirections are not handled, at least not in the preview: linking from MSE to MSO, and the other way around, still works when referring to new posts, just not so much for migrated posts. Like `meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-data-explorer` which currently redirects to `meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-data-explorer` and [is not rewritten with its old URL](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RAeJL.png) (at least not in the preview).

Answer (score 6):

I like this idea a lot, it would save me from having to generate links the "right" way and I do think it would make the site a lot cleaner. I think it would also make comments *much* more elegant. I do, however, fear that it might be a pain to implement. (Not sure about that, really depends a lot on how the backend works. As Brandon pointed out, it might not be that difficult after all.)

**EDIT:** *this is now supported:*

[Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/49435#49435)

**AWESOME!**

Comment: I don't think it'd be hard to implement, they've already done it with the close as exact duplicate function.

Comment: That's an excellent point.

Comment: @Brandon It's slightly different. Closing links are generated as part of the closing function, so the function can choose to format it as it likes. This proposal would be parsing actual post content and editing it.

Comment: @ccornet - duplicated links are inserted in the actual post content as well.

Comment: @Gnoupi But they're *inserted*. They aren't *edited from existing links*. Still feasible, but it's inaccurate to say it's the same.

Comment: @ccornet, you are absolutely right, I didn't consider the fact that one is automatic.

Comment: @ccornet: Amazon links are already [automatically rewritten](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links). Doesn't this imply that parsing and editing of content *already* takes place?

Comment: @ire I will concede that the functionality already exists (I never claimed it wasn't). But that's *not* part of the duplicate question linking functionality.

Answer (score 3):

To indicate that this is an automated link and more importantly to which SE-site it links, a small logo could be placed next to the question title

**edit** [feature-requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59569/146482)

Answer (score 3):

Could we not add a new button to the Toolbar - link to SE question.

[image]

This could open a popup where you

- Select the site that the question is on (drop down?)

  - Then search for the question to link to (similar to how the Title textbox works when asking a new question.)

    Or
  - Enter the question number to link to.

The popup validates that it is a valid question and then inserts the nice formatted link in to your answer/question for you.

I think it should handle multiple inserts elegantly too.  By that I mean it should take care of the " see here, here, here and here " type of linking.

**EDIT**

Pekka's comment on this has just got me thinking about this.

The process for selecting links could be shortened somewhat by simply getting the user to enter the question/answer id.  If one question or answer is found then it would simply add the nicely formatted link in.  If there is more than one ID e.g. exists in more than one site then user selected which one they want and it adds in.

Another way to do this would be to enable some kind of shortcut pattern which is converted to a nice link when posted. The shortcut pattern could be a site ID and then Q/A ID.

Entering `[SO:9033]` in a post would be transformed to [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) when posted.

Using 2-3 characters for the site code should be plenty enough to allow for existing sites and new sites.

Comment: this seems awfully complex compared to "paste link"

Comment: @Jeff how about making that work then?

Comment: @Pekka - I just added a couple more ideas in to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

It was not working in [this intra-site example](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4094/5):

[image]

If you click the above link you will see that the titles are now rendering correctly, but only because we edited the post to use much longer links, which are not the URLs we get from clicking the "share" button.

This also means that my userID of "5" is not included anywhere any more, and therefore I won't get the "announcer" badge when 25 people click one of the links.

Comment: @Luuklag What do you mean?

Comment: You wont get the badge for directing within the site anyways IIRC.

Comment: Links to answers aren't automatically converted to include the question title. Only links to questions are, for both the shortened form of the URL (with or without the `/userid` portion at the end) and the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea.

However, there is a problem with punctuation and capitalization.

> [C++ Beginner - Trouble using classes inside of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803910/c-beginner-trouble-using-classes-inside-of-classes)

would probably end up looking like

> [c beginner trouble using classes inside of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803910/c-beginner-trouble-using-classes-inside-of-classes)

Which, as you can see, kind of changes what the question is about (C++ to c). This would be a problem unless you were committing to do a DB lookup every time a link is typed in/submitted in a comment or answer, in order to the get the correctly cased and punctuated title. Those lookups may add up (look at how many links I used in this post alone, so isn't necessarily a good idea in terms of performance. Although, Jeff might just want to [throw some hardware at it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html).

**Simple Spec**

All links of the format

> "http://[((meta.)?stackoverflow|superuser|serverfault).com/questions/[\d]/ **< QuestionTitle>**"

(Could somebody fix my regex, I'm rusty)

would automatically be converted to

> [**< QuestionTitle>**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox)

Or, if the question title is too long

> [vb net how to require checkedlistbox...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773170/vb-net-how-to-require-checkedlistbox-to-have-at-least-one-item-selected-in-winfo) or [VB.NET: how to require CheckedListBo...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773170/vb-net-how-to-require-checkedlistbox-to-have-at-least-one-item-selected-in-winfo)

This would only be done once, at the time that the comment or question is initially linked. If the title of the question changes, the comment text would not change, because the link itself has not changed.

This magical replacement does not apply to people who are linking directly to answers, edit pages, or specific revisions. It could theoretically work for user pages, or tag pages.

**Second option**

A second alternate implementation would be to green jagged underline the link (like a grammar error), and have a rollover click option that says "convert to title hyperlink" or some such text. This would do the conversion that I described earlier, except that it would be optional. Further, because it would be replacing the text before the user has submitted the comment, it shows them how to do linking correctly (which they might not now) and it gives them the chance to change how it will appear. This is almost ALWAYS better than any "autocorrect" options. I hate autocorrect.

The (rather large) downside is that this would be more difficult to implement than a straight Regex replace.

Comment: Do close-question comments/links have that same punctuation/capitalization problem? If not, then we could mesh the title-fetching nature of those links instead of using the raw URL's title text. This would also allow people to post raw links with just the ID and benefit from this system (as sometimes occurs).

Comment: @ccornet I believe you are correct. The performance implications would not be very severe

Comment: what's do bad about a db lookup every time a link is typed in/submitted in a comment or answer?

Comment: @Ian, I suppose doing a lookup on post wouldn't be so bad. But doing it on every typed link would be terrible. We shouldn't be firing of possibly limitless db pings. It would easily open up for a malicious Denial of Service attack, even an accidental one.

Comment: How do you think the reputation is reported? I don't think they rewrite an HTML page everytime to record the rep on a certain page. There are DB Requests going on all over the place. That's what makes the site nice and dynamic. I don't follow your logic.