# Direct link to question using its ID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title)

Hi,

[In one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373741/how-can-i-randomly-place-several-non-colliding-rects/4373786#4373786), I've linked to some other relevant questions on SO. This required me to copy the questions's title text, paste it into the answer, copy the link, mark the title text, and paste the link into the pop up window.

It would be really handy if I could just paste the link inside the text body, and the editor would automatically add a site logo and the relevant text, like:

```
<site logo> How to sort an array in Python
```

Or, if pasting a link to an answer:

```
<site logo> John Doe's answer to *How to sort an array in Python*
```

**Addendum**

This works with questions:

[Direct link to question using its ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/direct-link-to-question-using-its-id)

But not with answers, because the link text only shows the question's title:

[Direct link to question using its ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/direct-link-to-question-using-its-id/71617#71617)

I still think a site logo and some info (Upvotes? Accepted?) would be nice.

Adam

Comment: Answers don't have titles of their own, right?

Comment: Of course, but I think you can benefit a lot from the `John Doe's answer to *How to sort an array in Python*` style.

Comment: (Ah, @Adam, my bad, totally missed that example when reading the addendum!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already done as of [a month ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483), it's just not shown in the preview window. For example, I typed `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/direct-link-to-question-using-its-id` below ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1cdf8463-8456-484b-a3bc-f3cb1251b9b1/view-source)):

[Direct link to question using its ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/direct-link-to-question-using-its-id)

It currently only works if the link is on the same site you're posting to (so e.g. posting an SO link on MSO won't work: [How can I randomly place several non-colliding rects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373741/how-can-i-randomly-place-several-non-colliding-rects) )