# Display the actual question title as the hyperlink for questions flagged as duplicates

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, 10k-tools, flags

When a user without close vote privileges flags a question as an exact duplicate of another question, their suggestion shows up in the 10k flags queue like so:

[image]

**See that ugly bare link?** Can we change that hyperlink text to the *actual title* of the proposed duplicate question?

The title of a question is a heck of a lot more meaningful than the numeric ID displayed in the link (at least to us humans).

[We already do this automatically for inter-site links posted in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title), so it *seems* like it should be relatively easy to do here as well.

I suppose it's not really that big of a deal, considering that you have to click on the link anyway to read the suggested question and decide if it is actually a duplicate. But stuff like this goes a lot way towards the appearance of "fit and finish", and it also makes it easier for people like me with terrible short-term memory to recall the fuzzy memory of a question's topic immediately upon seeing the title.