# Why is there a difference between rendering of links in tag-wiki and in editing preview?

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks, tag-wiki, markdown-preview

I have recently edited [this tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/2709/revisions) on MathOverflow.

Only now I have noticed that links are shown as bare urls:

[image: screenshot of the tag-wiki]

On the other hand, when editing, the links are rendered as titles of the question in the preview.

[image: screenshot of the edit window]

Of course, I should have been more careful and notice this after checking the end result of my edit. (As you can see, I have made two revisions to that tag-wiki and still I somehow was able to miss this.)

Still it would be nice to have consistent behavior between preview and final result. (And it would be even nicer if the links would be rendered in tag-wikis as titles - the same way they are rendered in posts.)

---

**EDIT:** Curiously, here is an example of a [tag-wiki on another site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-history/info) where link to meta.SE post is rendered as a title, although the source [only contains url](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/24912/revisions).

Comment: AFAIK the title look-up should only be done while you're on the same site. So the server-side parser did the correct thing. So I suspect the client-side editor/parser is at fault here.

Comment: @rene Here is a specific example showing [an answer with link to meta.SE](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/541/how-do-i-use-the-comment-notification-system/542#542). If you check [revision history](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/542/revisions) and [source](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/1c89a794-4d1c-4111-a8c8-a11308d63e97/view-source) of this particular post, you can see that the source contains only url, but it is rendered as the title of the question. (After your comment I have doubts about this - but I suppose it is documented somewhere how this *should* behave.)

Comment: Since this is marked as status-completed, it seems that it works at least for some sites: [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49433)

Comment: The example you found was part of automatic script and I assume that only fixed the server-side rendering/html. If you add another revision to that post it will break again would be my guess.

Comment: @rene Here is [another example](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25830/how-could-i-attach-a-pdf-file/25831#25831) which was not influenced by the script correcting meta.SO to meta.SE. And [link to revision history](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/25831/revisions).
And if we want example from MathOverflow, then [this answer](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2917/bug-with-marshal-badge/2918#2918), here is link to [the revision history](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/2918/revisions). I have added example of tag-info from another site to my post - it works there.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Something is off there. Maybe the http/https change did introduce this regression.

Comment: I have created a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/639358) that finds such links so it makes it easier to inspect multiple cases. There is something weird going on for sure.